# Regarding Python Program to calculate the distance between oxygen of one water molecule with hydrogens of other water molecules

Tags: python, distance

I have a trajectory for 0.5 ps each after md simulation in gromacs. I want to calculate the distance between oxygen of one water molecule(OW) with the hydrogens of other water molecules (HW1,HW2)ie., distance between OW of 28SOL and HW1,HW2 of 30SOL,distance between OW of 28SOL and HW1,HW2 of 31SOL and for all combinations  for t=0.00, for t=0.500....

```
Generated by trjconv : Protein t=   0.00000
   28SOL     OW  115   0.439   0.940   1.110
   28SOL    HW1  116   0.462   1.020   1.055
   28SOL    HW2  117   0.414   0.864   1.050
   29SOL     OW  118   1.626   1.796   1.779
   29SOL    HW1  119   1.550   1.763   1.834
   29SOL    HW2  120   1.594   1.871   1.720
   30SOL     OW  121   1.022   0.116   0.460
   30SOL    HW1  122   0.955   0.125   0.533
   30SOL    HW2  123   1.002   0.182   0.388
   31SOL     OW  124   1.063   0.349   1.874
   31SOL    HW1  125   1.028   0.428   1.824
   31SOL    HW2  126   1.129   0.300   1.816
   32SOL     OW  127   1.726   0.716   1.886
   32SOL    HW1  128   1.737   0.680   1.793
   32SOL    HW2  129   1.799   0.782   1.905
.
.
.
Generated by trjconv : Protein t=   0.50000
   28SOL     OW  115   0.494   1.029   1.115
   28SOL    HW1  116   0.529   1.116   1.080
   28SOL    HW2  117   0.465   0.971   1.039
   29SOL     OW  118   1.566   1.834   1.772
   29SOL    HW1  119   1.556   1.767   1.846
   29SOL    HW2  120   1.476   1.864   1.742
   30SOL     OW  121   0.913   0.070   0.385
   30SOL    HW1  122   0.876   0.086   0.477
   30SOL    HW2  123   0.880   0.142   0.323
   31SOL     OW  124   1.089   0.344   1.872
   31SOL    HW1  125   1.028   0.403   1.820
   31SOL    HW2  126   1.154   0.300   1.809
.
.
.
```

How can i write a python code to calculate the distance for this...

Comment: Most of us are not physicists ,  if you are asking a programming question then provide a written algorithm and we can help you convert it to code.  If you are asking a chemistry/physics question,  I don't think you are in the right place.

Comment: Can i knw the right place to post and get my doubts cleared..?? any forum/web pages..??

Comment: There is chemistryhelpforum.com, and probably others. If you can detail the algorithm, someone can help you turn it into code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what gmx distance does, with the right choices of index groups.